# How to develop $(n+1)^{p+1}-1=(p+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p + \text{terms for } \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r \text{, for r < p}$?

Tags: calculus

So, I am really sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am trying to solve a problem (Spivak $2-7$) for which there is a part where I have
$$
(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1} = (p+1)k^p + \text{terms involving lower powers of k}.
$$
as in
$$
(k+1)^{p+1}-k^{p+1} = (p+1)k^p + Ak^{p-1} + Bk^{p-2}+...
$$
where the author develops this expression for k = $1,...,n$.
From which **I get**
$$
(n+1)^{p+1}-1=(p+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p + \text{terms for } \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r \text{, for r < p}
\tag{1}
$$
the latter part of the equation from which I stole from the author, but I understand that part, the issue is that the author gets:
$$
\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p + \text{terms for } \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r \text{, for r < p}
\tag{2}
$$
**My question is, how do we get from (1) to (2)?** A
[similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198842/spivak-chapter-2-problem-7)
question I have looked at derives this:
$$
\frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1} - \frac{1}{p+1}
\tag{3} =\sum_{k=1}^n k^p + \sum_{k=1}^n \mathcal{O}(k^r)
$$
(where $\mathcal{O}(k^r)$ represents the terms for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^r \text{, for r < p}$)

which seems more understandable than (2) as in (3) I see that the answerer just divided the identity by $(p+1)$, **from which I also mean to ask, can you divide the terms in $\mathcal{O}(k^r)$ and still keep $\mathcal{O}(k^r)$?** What I mean by this is that when the term $\mathcal{O}(k^r)$ represents $Ak^{p-1} + Bk^{p-2}+...$, can you still call $\frac{\mathcal{O}(k^r)$}{p+1}$, $\mathcal{O}(k^r)$? The reason I find (3) more understandable than (2) is that at least in (3), the "$-1$" term remains, where did the "$-1$" term go in (2)!?

I am very sorry if this question represents the utmost stupidity in me, and if the question is stupid in itself, thank you.

Comment: This title was my best attempt, I don't mind someone editing my post with a better title in mind.

Comment: From (2) to (3), we notice that $1=k^0$

Comment: @Leon I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future: Leon meant "From (1) to (2)", not "(2) to (3)" in the comment above, read the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that this is the answer that you are expecting.

First, notice that
$$1=k^0.$$
Since we only focus on $k^p$ and any $k^r$ with $r<p$ will be put in the remainder term. Thus you can ignore $1=k^0$ to move from (1) to (2).

Second, for fixed natural number $r$ and fixed real constant $c$
$$O(k^r)=O(c k^r)=c O(k^r)$$
as $O(k^r)$ means any polynomial of $k$ of order less than or equal to $r$.

Comment: "Thus you can ignore it to move from (2) to (3).", are you referring to the $-1$ I was referring to?

Comment: Yes, it is what I mean!

Comment: So, $O(k^r)$ + $1$ ($k^0$) = $O(k^r)$?

Comment: Yes exactly, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118173/discussion-between-leon-and-sdavid552).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way
to get the recurrence
for the power sums.

If
$s_m(n)
=\sum_{k=0}^n k^m
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
(n+1)^m
&=\sum_{k=0}^n ((k+1)^m-k^m)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}k^j)\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}\sum_{k=0}^nk^j\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{j}s_j(n)\\
&= ms_{m-1}(n)+\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{j}s_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
s_{m-1}(n)
&=\dfrac1{m}\left((n+1)^m-\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{j}s_j(n)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{m}\left(\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{m}{j}n^j-\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{j}s_j(n)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{m}\left(n^m+mn^{m-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{j}n^j-\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{j}s_j(n)\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{m}\left(n^m+mn^{m-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{j}(n^j-s_j(n))\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Immediately,
$s_m(n)
\lt \dfrac1{m+1}(n+1)^{m+1}
$.