# Spivak calculus chapter 2 question 7.

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have a question regarding this solution ([Spivak Chapter 2 Problem 7](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198842/spivak-chapter-2-problem-7)). Why is the answer $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p + \sum_{k=1}^n \mathcal{O}(k^r)= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(k+1)^{p+1} - k^{p+1}}{p+1} = \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

The question in the textbook asks us to show that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \frac{(n+1)^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

I am confused about how the  $$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathcal{O}(k^r)$$ gets absorbed into the RHS.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: It would be good if you tell us what $\mathcal O$ means.

Comment: You are misreading the question. It does not show equality, just that the term can be written in terms of powers of $n$ less than $p+1$.

Comment: I guess $r=p-1.$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net it means terms involving